# TYPO3 v10.4.9 - Speaking URLs not working

Tags: url, typo3

I installed TYPO3 v10.4.9 with boostrap package and created a few custom pages to try things out. I noticed that the "speaking URLs" are not working and I have no idea why. Note that I am a total bigginer in TYPO3, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Example:
We have a page called Photos. The URL created by "URL Segment" in Page module > "Edit page properties" is https://example.com/photos and the ID of the page is 84.

If I click on the view icon in the Page module, URL https://example.com/photos opens in the frontend and I get a message that says "Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server".

On the other hand, if I type URL with ID in the browser manually, like so: https://example.com/index.php?id=84, it works perfectly fine. This problem is present for every page I create.
I have created site configuration. Below is the content of config.yaml:

```
base: 'https://example.com'
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling: {  }
languages:
    title: 'Example Site'
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    websiteTitle: ''
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ''
    flag: us
    languageId: '0'
rootPageId: 1
routes: {  }
websiteTitle: ''
```

.htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php

#@__HCP_END__@#
# Anything after the comment above is left alone
```

Please help. What am I missing here?
If I should paste some more data to help resolve the problem, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I copied contents of

https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess

to .htaccess and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the .htaccess is missing in the root of your installation.

Comment: Or you are using nginx without the necessary configuration https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html#nginx

Comment: Stephan Grass thank you for reply. There is a .htacccess in the root of my installation but it does not seem to be configured. I added the content of it above. Can you suggest how to configure it? Thank you.

@Jonas Eberle I am not using nginx, but thank you for asking.